# How many set will result from sorting $n$ objects into sets of $m$ elements such that each set overlaps with each other set by $p$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

I have $n$ items and I would like to sort them into set of $m$ items. I would like to create these sets such that every pair of sets shares exactly $p$ elements. Additionally, all elements should be used the same number of times. Assuming this is possible with a given triplet $(n, m, p)$, what is the maximum number of sets one may construct?

A few examples: $(a, b, 0)$ yields $\frac{a}{b}$, $(q, q-1, q-2)$ yields $q$, $(n, 2, 1)$ yields $\frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}$, and $(7, 3, 1)$ yields $7$.

Thank you for any help you may provide.

Comment: The word "group" has a specific meaning in mathematics. Do you mean "set" instead?

Comment: I'm aware, but I thought it the meaning was clear. Apparently not, so here ya go!

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, so the question "how many sets will result" does not have a definite answer. Are you asking about the _maximum_ number of sets satisfying the conditions?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @MichaelRiberdy Thank you for clarifying, and sorry for being pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not so clear. Anyway, I hope this can help.

Let us fix the number of sets $N$, each of which will have $m$ items and assume that each pair of sets shares exactly $p$ items.

How many items $n$ will there be?
I will say
$$ n = N * m - \binom{N}{2} * p . $$
In fact, we can count $m$ items for each set and then subtract $p$ items for each pair of sets.

Furthermore, each element will be exactly in $k$ sets, where $k$ is given by
$$ n * k = N * m , $$
which means
$$ k = \frac{N * m}{n} = \frac{N * m}{N * m - \binom{N}{2} * p} .$$

Now, let us assume that a triplet $(n,m,p)$ is given. We can re-write the question as follows: Find $(k,N)$ such that the equations are satisfied and $N$ is maximum.